# How to override protected function Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, overrides, customer-attribute

i want to edit this function in Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute.php

```
protected function _updateDefaultValue($object, $optionId, $intOptionId, &$defaultValue)
{
    if (in_array($optionId, $object->getDefault())) {
        $frontendInput = $object->getFrontendInput();
        if ($frontendInput === 'multiselect') {
            $defaultValue[] = $intOptionId;
        } elseif ($frontendInput === 'select') {
            $defaultValue = [$intOptionId];
        }
    }
}
```

I want to check if $ frontendInput == 'checkboxes'
I have override this file but can't. who knows any other way?
Please helpe me! tks.

this is my code

```
class Attribute extends \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute{

protected function _updateDefaultValue($object, $optionId, $intOptionId, &$defaultValue)
{
    if (in_array($optionId, $object->getDefault())) {
        $frontendInput = $object->getFrontendInput();
        if ($frontendInput === 'multiselect' || $frontendInput === 'checkboxs') {
            $defaultValue[] = $intOptionId;
        } elseif ($frontendInput === 'select' || $frontendInput === 'radio') {
            $defaultValue = [$intOptionId];
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: You can use <preference> to override Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute.php and override only _updateDefaultValue() function.

Comment: yes.i tried <preference> but  It does not fit into my override function.i have updated my question.

Comment: What is the reason for overiding this function ?

Comment: @aravind 
because the field checkbox in my backend does not receive the default value. I need to override this function to set the default value for it.

Answer (score 1):

Also In preference method,You can not override a protected function. However you can override the public method which is calling that protected method. In your case, It is also a protected method.

Comment: Do you know any way ?

Comment: It is difficult to overide that function in your case, as everywhere it get's called is protected. So, You need to find an alternate solution..

Comment: I have been thinking about this problem for more than 6 hours but still haven't found an alternative solution. Anyway, thank you.~~!

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin and do following in **beforeupdateDefaultValue**

```
    if ($frontendInput === 'multiselect' || $frontendInput === 'checkboxs'){
         //setFrontendInput to 'multiselect';
    }elseif($frontendInput === 'select' || $frontendInput === 'radio'){
         //setFrontendInput to 'select';
    }
```

Comment: According to docs plugins cant be used on non public methods https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: it is protected function .can not used plugin.

Comment: Can I see how the checkbox is implemented. Or any other method calling it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved through preferences,

Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Wishlist" 
    type="Vendor\Module\Block\Share\Wishlist"/>
```

Vendor/Module/Block/Share/Email/Items.php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Share\Email;

```
class Items extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Email\Items
{
     protected function _createWishlistItemCollection() {
       ......
    }
}
```